# Hide same elements in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem I want to solve with jQuery. In a list, I want to check if two items have the same text, and if so I want to delete the second one.

I am not really sure how to go about it.

The markup is simple, kinda like this

```
<ul>
    <li>Text1</li>
    <li>Text2</li>
    <li>Text1</li>
    <li>Text3</li>
    <li>Text3</li>
    <li>Text4</li>
<ul>
```

I cannot use an active/inactive class because this list is dynamic and I don't know in advance how it's going to be populated.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.inArray for a tmp array would work.

```js
  
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var tmparr = [];
  $('.list li').each(function(i,item){
    if($.inArray($(this).text(), tmparr) >= 0){
      $(this).remove();
    }else{
      tmparr.push($(this).text());
    }
 });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="list">
    <li>Text1</li>
    <li>Text2</li>
    <li>Text1</li>
    <li>Text3</li>
    <li>Text3</li>
    <li>Text4</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this e.g. like this:

```
var unique = {};
$('li').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  if (unique[txt])
    $(this).remove();
  else
    unique[txt] = true;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mpfhg0b/)

As explanation: `unique` is initialized as object. While `each()` iterates over all `li` elements, the `if (unique[txt])` is `true` in case  it was previously set to `true` for the text of the `li` currently processed. In this case the current `li` will be removed. If not, `unique[txt]` for the text of the current `li` is set to true and added to `unique`. As it might not be clear what `unique` finally contains:  `{ Text1=true, Text2=true, Text3=true, Text4=true }`

Comment: Thanks, very elegant, I like it although I don't understand it fully :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over your li elements and store their text in an array.  If the text for the ith element is already in the array, skip it.  Once you have an array of unique text strings, remove all li elements and generate new ones from the information in your array.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/k255o52e/1/

```
$('ul li').each(function () {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    // finds all LI that contain the same text
    // excludes the first element
    var $li = $('li:contains("' + txt + '"):not(:first)');
    // and removes the other
    $li.remove();

})
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$('ul li').each(function () {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    var $li = $('li:contains("' + txt + '"):not(:first)').filter(function(index)
    {
        return $(this).text() === txt;
    });
    $li.remove();

})
```

Comment: This is also very good, now I wonder which method is the more efficient, they are all equally good

Comment: This solution can have error when two or more objects have the similar text. See an example http://jsfiddle.net/k255o52e/2/